# Java monthly compound interest

Tags: java, string

I needed to write a program to calculate monthly compounding interest using a for loop based on user input values. But I am having some problems.

Example input and output should look like:

Please input the following:  principal, interest rate, term >> 1000 5 54 months

```
Month:  Interest:   Principal:
   1    $4.17       $1004.17 
   2    $4.18       $1008.35 
   etc. etc.        etc.
```

My problem is string input validation. If a user types anything other than months or years it should inform them and reprompt to enter again. However with my current code it just keeps asking the user to enter months or years even if they've entered months or years.

```
public Calculator() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean error = false;

    while (!error) {
        System.out
                .print("Please input the following: principal, interest rate, term >> ");
        double principal = input.nextDouble();
        double interest_rate = input.nextDouble();
        int term = input.nextInt();
        String MonthOrYear = input.nextLine();
        double amount = 0;

        if (interest_rate <= 0 || term <= 0 || principal <= 0) {
            System.out
                    .println("The term, interest rate and principal must be greater than zero");
            continue;
        }
        if (!MonthOrYear.equals("month") || (!MonthOrYear.equals("year"))) {
            System.out.println("Please input either month or year");
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println("Month:  " + "  Interest:  " + "Principal:  ");

        for (int month = 1; month <= term; month++) {
            double interest = principal * interest_rate / 100;
            principal = principal + interest;
            System.out.printf("%4d %10.2f %10.2f\n", month, interest,
                    principal);

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if (!MonthOrYear.equals("month") || (!MonthOrYear.equals("year"))) this condition is always true, regardless of the value of MonthOrYear, it should be && and not ||

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a common mistake when nextInt and nextLine used. 
Change your line:

```
String MonthOrYear = input.nextLine();
```

by:

```
String MonthOrYear = input.next();
```